# Issue with JaCoCo after migrating Quarkus from 2.16 to 3.6.4

Tags: quarkus, jacoco, java-17

I recently performed a migration of my Quarkus project from version 2.16 to 3.6.4 using the Quarkus CLI (quarkus update). The update process went smoothly, and the Maven packages were upgraded successfully.

However, when attempting to run the project using mvn quarkus:dev, I encountered an issue related to JaCoCo. The logs indicate the following problem:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_4481564/Offline

```
13:46:03 ERROR [traceId=,spanId=] [io.qu.de.de.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.common.deployment.ResteasyReactiveCommonProcessor#handleApplication threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to handle class: tn.wecraft.bore.Application
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.processor.scanning.ResteasyReactiveScanner.scanForApplicationClass(ResteasyReactiveScanner.java:117)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.common.deployment.ResteasyReactiveCommonProcessor.handleApplication(ResteasyReactiveCommonProcessor.java:181)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.processor.scanning.ResteasyReactiveScanner.scanForApplicationClass(ResteasyReactiveScanner.java:99)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_4481564/Offline
        at tn.wecraft.bore.Application.$jacocoInit(Application.java)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.BootstrapMethodInvoker.invoke(BootstrapMethodInvoker.java:90)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.ConstantBootstraps.makeConstant(ConstantBootstraps.java:72)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkDynamicConstantImpl(MethodHandleNatives.java:337)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkDynamicConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:329)
        at tn.wecraft.bore.Application.<init>(Application.java)
        ... 18 more
```

I've tried investigating the issue, but I'm unsure how to resolve it. Here are the steps I've taken so far:

Verified that all the dependencies are correctly updated after the Quarkus migration.
Checked the JaCoCo plugin configuration in my pom.xml file.
I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this JaCoCo issue post Quarkus migration. Thank you!

Additional Information:

Quarkus version before migration: 2.16
Quarkus version after migration: 3.6.4
Relevant portions of the pom.xml related to JaCoCo configuration.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jacoco</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
...
...
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                        <argLine>-Dquarkus.test.hang-detection-timeout=10s -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=FR</argLine>
                        <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
                        <runOrder>random</runOrder>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>30</forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <jacoco-agent.destfile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-ut.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                            <user.language>en</user.language>
                            <user.region>FR</user.region>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>integration-tests</id>
                            <phase>integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                                </includes>
                                <systemPropertyVariables>
                                    <jacoco-agent.destfile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec
                                    </jacoco-agent.destfile>
                                </systemPropertyVariables>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-jacoco-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>before-unit-test-execution</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                                <propertyName>surefire.jacoco.args</propertyName>
                                <exclClassLoaders>*QuarkusClassLoader</exclClassLoaders>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>instrument-ut</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>instrument</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>restore-ut</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>after-unit-test-execution</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut-coverage-report
                                </outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>after-integration-test-execution</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-quarkus.exec</dataFile>
                                <outputDirectory>
                                    ${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it-coverage-report
                                </outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>merge-unit-and-integration</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>merge</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <fileSets>
                                    <fileSet>
                                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>*.exec</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileSet>
                                </fileSets>
                                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/merged.exec</destFile>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>create-merged-report</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/merged.exec</dataFile>
                                <outputDirectory>
                                    ${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-merged-test-coverage-report
                                </outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>check</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>check</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <rules>
                                    <rule implementation="org.jacoco.maven.RuleConfiguration">
                                        <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                        <limits>
                                            <limit implementation="org.jacoco.report.check.Limit">
                                                <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                                                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                                <minimum>${jacoco.coverage.min}</minimum>
                                            </limit>
                                        </limits>
                                    </rule>
                                </rules>
                                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/merged.exec</dataFile>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
...
```